# Is XP earned every time one acts according to one's alignment?

Tags: experience-points, dungeon-world

In *Dungeon World* a character earns XP for following his alignment. Is this XP earned every time the character follows his alignment or only at the session's end?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is only at the end of the session.

From page 30 of the rulebook:

> Acting according to your alignment and fulfilling the conditions of your alignment moves will grant you XP at the end of each session

And from page 78:

> If you fulfilled that alignment at least once this session, mark XP.

Comment: It is worth noting that the assignment is part of the **End of Session** move, along with bond resolving and session XP.